# Linear Scale Django form widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I am looking for some guidance in order to create a widget that is not documented at all in the django documentation but is an evident part of forms. 
And I am talking about Linear Scales widgets for forms. Giving the ability to a user to choose on a scale between 1-100 a score

If you have any idea on how to do it, any direction I would be please to get it ;)

thx you very much

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want a `type="range"` input as you can find in this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) page.

Django doesn't provide this kind of [field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#core-field-arguments) out of the box and you have to do it yourself or find a library that implements it.

To implement a field you should look at the Field [API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/fields/#Field) and the Input [API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/).

```
# example input
from django.form.widgets import Input

class RangeInput(Input):
    input_type = 'range'
    template_name = 'path/to/input/template.html'
```

You should also implement type coercion (to int of float) and range checking to be sure that you can validate a form and store it appropriately in the db.

Once you have done that you can create your form with this input or create a new `RangeField` for models and link it to the `RangeInput` element.